# External function call failure

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to remove a folder to Recycle Bin in my installer.
I wrote a function (uses `SHFileOperation`) which is working fine in install mode and not working in uninstall mode. `Inno Setup` shows some weird errors in both 5 and 6 versions (different ones).
Is it a bug or me doing something wrong? Are there any workarounds?

Inno Setup 5:

> Runtime Error (at 2:67): Internal error: An attempt was made to access WizardForm before it has been created.

Inno Setup 6:

> Runtime error (at 2:82): Could not call proc.

The code is below.

```
; -- Example1.iss --
; Demonstrates copying 3 files and creating an icon.

; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING .ISS SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
WizardStyle=modern
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"

[Code]

type
  TSHFileOpStruct = record
    hwnd: HWND;
    wFunc: UINT;
    pFrom: string;
    pTo: string;
    fFlags: Word;
    fAnyOperationsAborted: BOOL; 
    hNameMappings: HWND;
    lpszProgressTitle: string;
  end; 

const
  FO_COPY            = $0002;
  FO_DELETE          = $0003;
  FOF_SILENT         = $0004;
  FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = $0010;
  FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR = $0020;
  FOF_ALLOWUNDO      = $0040;
  FOF_NOERRORUI      = $0400;
  FOF_NO_UI          = $0434; //(FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR);

function SHFileOperation(lpFileOp: TSHFileOpStruct): Integer;
external 'SHFileOperationW@shell32.dll stdcall';

function MoveToTrash(path: string) : Boolean;
var
  FileOp: TSHFileOpStruct;
  FromPath: string;
begin
  FromPath := path + #0;
  FileOp.hwnd := WizardForm.Handle;
  FileOp.wFunc := FO_DELETE;
  FileOp.pFrom := FromPath;
  FileOp.fFlags := $0474; //(FOF_ALLOWUNDO | OF_SILENT);
  Result := SHFileOperation(FileOp) = 0;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  res : Integer;
begin
  if CurStep=ssInstall then begin
    MoveToTrash('c:\9'); // WORKS FINE HERE
  end;
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  res : Integer;
begin
  if CurUninstallStep=usUninstall then begin
    MoveToTrash('c:\9'); // GETTING WEIRD ERROR HERE
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in this:

```
FileOp.hwnd := WizardForm.Handle;
```

This solved it:

```
FileOp.hwnd := 0;
```